# What user, group to use in a docker image (if not the default root)?

Tags: docker

I've read that it is best if not the root (0) user is being used to run the app inside a container.

I can specify a user in the Dockerfile using the `USER` instruction while creating the image.

Do I just choose something random and hope it does not already exist on the host machine?

Will it be the same user with the same groups **as if** it was on the host machine?
(What is the relationship between the user inside the container and outside on the host?)

Should I just always leave the `USER` as a parameter (`ARG`)?

Comment: The point of not using `root` is that `root` has special privileges from the kernel's perspective (to the extent that they haven't been switched off with capabilities &c., but assuming that every kernel driver loaded is using capabilities appropriately is placing trust where none is needed). _Literally anything besides root_ does not run that risk. There's no reason to try to avoid UIDs used in the host -- they're different namespaces; that's the point.

Comment: That said, I'd argue that this is off-topic here; it's more a system administration question than a software development one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think the `Dockerfile` part of docker is the responsibility of the software developer, but you can move this to serverfault or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I just choose something random and hope it does not already exist on the host machine?

You don't particularly care if it exists on the host machine or not. From the perspective of things running inside the container, the host machine doesn't exist. From the perspective of the host machine, files owned by the container may have odd user and group names associated with them, but that's okay, and that's why everything is isolated inside the Docker storage area.

> Will it be the same user with the same groups as if it was on the host machine?
> (What is the relationship between the user inside the container and outside on the host?)

Users in the container have no relation to users on the host. Inside a container there is a unique `/etc/{passwd, groups, etc}` that are distinct from those on the host. User id 1000 on the host may be "bob" but inside the container may be "apache".

> Should I just always leave the USER as a parameter (ARG)?

Unless your image is meant to somehow integrate with filesystems on the host, which is not a usual use case, there's no reason to make this a build argument. Just pick a UID and use it.

It's always possible for someone to change the UID under which a container is running with the `--user` (`-u`) argument to `docker run`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to ask for a little clarification on this part: _user id 1000 on the host may be "bob" but inside the container may be "apache"_ -> So is it possible that my "apache" container creates a file on a volume which is seen on the host as if the file was created by "bob"? If so, is this OK from a security standpoint?

Comment: *So is it possible that my "apache" container creates a file on a volume which is seen on the host as if the file was created by "bob"?* Yes, that's possible. It's not much of a security concern because volumes are located inside the Docker storage area, which requires privileged access (typically `root`).